# download file from file:// prepended with libcurl in c++

Tags: c++, linux, file, libcurl

I was asked for my library management c++ project to get access to library file only by its ***file://*** included URL...
I used Libcurl because of same tag words of it when I was searching.

is downloading of a file through Libcurl (as it said it's compatible) ,a right way to do it?

> command line tool and library
>   for transferring data with URLs
>   Supports...
>   DICT, **FILE**, ...

the libcurl code was

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
int downloadTO(const void* downloadURL, const void* OUTPUT_FILE_NAME)
{
CURL *curl_handle;
static const char *pagefilename = (char*)OUTPUT_FILE_NAME;
FILE *pagefile;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

/* init the curl session */
curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

/* set URL to get here */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, (char*)downloadURL);

/* Switch on full protocol/debug output while testing */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

/* disable progress meter, set to 0L to enable and disable debug output */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);

/* send all data to this function  */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

/* open the file */
pagefile = fopen(pagefilename, "wb");
if(pagefile)
{

    /* write the page body to this file handle */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pagefile);

    /* get it! */
    curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

    /* close the header file */
    fclose(pagefile);
}

/* cleanup curl stuff */
curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

return 0;
}
```

---

can I also get access to the file with its ***file://*** prepended URL with the sockets?

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking. If you're accessing: can you access the file using the file URI, then yes. `echo "Some content" >> file.txt; curl file://"$(pwd)"/file.txt`.

Comment: Do you have any C++ code that demonstrates **what you've tried**? This is the important thing here. It may well work, you've identified that it says it in the documentation, so you need to make an attempt to find out.

Comment: I wanted to find other way of doing the same thing. @AlexanderHuszagh any c++ native library solutions?

Comment: @tadman yes It works, but is there any way to get access to the file with a different approach?

Comment: If you have a URI that begins with `file://` then *theoretically* you can resolve that to a path and use regular file operations to get the data. Or you can do it this way and not care. I say if your code works then that's great, problem solved. If it has performance problems then, and only then would you dig into it some more.

Comment: @tadman is the curl doing the same thing?

Comment: Internally? That's the only way to read files.